# How do I detect empty cells in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell-array, is-empty

How do I detect empty cells in a cell array? I know the command to remove the empty cell is `a(1) = []`, but I can't seem to get MATLAB to automatically detect which cells are empty.

Background: 
I preallocated a cell array using `a=cell(1,53)`. 
Then I used `if exist(filename(i))` and textscan to check for a file, and read it in. As a result, when the `filename(i)` does not exist, an empty cell results and we move onto the next file.

When I'm finished reading in all the files, I would like to delete the empty cells of `a`. I tried `if a(i)==[]`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html)

```
%# find empty cells
emptyCells = cellfun(@isempty,a);
%# remove empty cells
a(emptyCells) = [];
```

Note: `a(i)==[]` won't work. If you want to know whether the the i-th cell is empty, you have to use curly brackets to access the content of the cell. Also, `==[]` evaluates to empty, instead of `true`/`false`, so you should use the command `isempty` instead. In short: `a(i)==[]` should be rewritten as `isempty(a{i})`.

Comment: for a slight improvement in speed use `emptyCells = cellfun('isempty', a);` ... `cellfun` has an internal `switch` statement which checks to see whether the string is one of a handful of functions which it can do a "magic" speed increase with ... This is described here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost/

Comment: +1 for specifying how to delete the empty cells!this leaves you with a cell array containing only the non-empty entries!

Comment: Ten years later and `'isempty'` is *still* 70x faster than `@isempty`.

Answer (score 0):

All above mentioned answers are incorrect, because in my case when i used them, they removed empty cells and then all elements of my cell array situated in a row manner instead of preserving their actual shape. In fact after using this kind of approach your cell array elements tend to be a row cell vector.

I have found this approach which works correctly in my case.

source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.softsys.matlab/p3NX0fI6u90

approach:

```
myCellARRAY(all(cellfun(@isempty,myCellARRAY),2), : ) = [];
```