# manipulation of a cell array-

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array where some cells are empty, some are with numbers and some are with strings and chars. I want to  find out which ones are empty- is there a better way then a  double loop with the following formula:

```
isempty(cell_array{i,j})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect empty cells in a cell array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400515/how-do-i-detect-empty-cells-in-a-cell-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
  emptyList = cellfun(@isempty, yourCellArrayHere);
```

It is more compact, and Matlab-like style. In practice, it is not guaranteed to be faster, due to JIT optimizations of `for` loops.