# Matlab - Why ismember does not work?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell vector with different & redundant company names. And a list of interesting companies. I try to figure out, where in the big matrix the interesting companies appear. I am interested in all appearances.
My Code for some reason does not work. the ismember returns always an error.

```
Comps = Data0(:,7);
for i = 1: length(relCompQ)
    comp = relCompQ{i,1};
    c(:,i) = find(ismember(Comps,comp));
end
```

errors:

> Error using cell/ismember>cellismemberR2012a (line 192) Input A of
>   class cell and input B of class char must be cell arrays of strings,
>   unless one is a string.

Error in cell/ismember (line 56)

> [varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] = cellismemberR2012a(A,B);

Both Vectors have values like: 'Nike', 'Adidas', 'BMW' etc.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Define what your variables are; and preferably include a smalll example. The code you have posted can't be understood without knowing that

Comment: Done:
Error using cell/ismember>cellismemberR2012a (line 192) Input A of class cell and input B of class char must be cell arrays of strings, unless one is a string.

Error in cell/ismember (line 56) [varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] = cellismemberR2012a(A,B);

Both Vectors have values like: 'Nike', 'Adidas', 'BMW' etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Input A of class cell and input B of class char must be cell arrays of strings, unless one is a string.

This means that every entry in the cell must be a string, and in this case it's not. If your cell array contains numeric values, or even an *empty* matrix, you will get this error.

For example, this is fine (cell array of strings, and a char)

```
ismember({'b','c'},'b');
```

This is not:

```
ismember({'b',[1 2]},'b');
ismember({'b',[]},'b');
ismember({'b',NaN},'b');
```

The most likely one to get mixed into your cell array accidentally is probably the empty matrix.  In these cases I always recommend using the debugging tools (`dbstop if error` is our friend), to doublecheck exactly what is going on.  What you think the variable should be or contain, and what it **does** in fact contain, are not always the same thing.

If it does contain empties, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400515/how-do-i-detect-empty-cells-in-a-cell-array) for ideas on how to deal with it.