# How do I use matlab ismember in data structures with multiple nested fields?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, data-structures, indices

In matlab I have the following 2 data structures b and c defined as follows.

```
b(1).b = struct('c',{'a', 'b', 'c'})
c(1).b = struct('c',{'b', 'a', 'c'})
```

Now I want to use `ismember` to find out if the elements of b(1).b.c are contained in c(1).b.c and if so, which indices of c(1).b.c each of the elements belong to.

For example: `b(1).b(1).c = a`, I want to backtrace this to structure `c` to find which index of structure `c`  'a' belongs to (it should return 2 since 'a' is the second element of structure `c`).

I have tried

```
[~, ind] = ismember({b(1).b.c},{c(1).b.c})
```

which has worked for me previously with a different data structure but I now receive the following error:

```
*Error using cell/ismember>cellismemberR2012a (line 192)
Input A of class cell and input B of class cell must be cell arrays of      strings, unless one is a string.
Error in cell/ismember (line 56)
[varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] = cellismemberR2012a(A,B);*
```

I am not sure why its not working. Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Using your exact code in R2011a (Version 7.12.0.635) works as you expect giving [2 1 3].  What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Interesting, it also worked for me as well

Comment: Fine in 2012b as well. Are there any other variables in your Matlab workspace that might be conflicting? (For example, is there already a structure `b`?)

Comment: According [this similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227291/matlab-why-ismember-does-not-work) (duplicate?), the error arises when the data is not homogeneous.  Is the sample given the actual set of data generating the error?

Comment: @tall.b.lo I'm using R2014a.

Comment: @TroyHaskin nope this is not the data set, I can't provide the original data set because its huge so I made one up with a similar structure...

Comment: @David nope... no other conflicting variables...

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui Is all of your data of the same type and non-empty?

Comment: @TroyHaskin yup its all the same and non-empty... I have found a solution, I'll post it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following to work.

First assigning `b(1).b.c` to an array `S` and then comparing that with the data structure `c` using `ismember`.

```
S = [b(1).b.c]
S = S'
[~, ind] = ismember(S,{c(1).b.c})
```

I have found this to work.

Also,

```
[~, ind] = ismember([b(1).b.c}],[c(1).b.c])
```

does not give an error but all the values in `ind` are `zero` which is not true for the data.

Thanks all for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Googling around did not show any possible solutions but there are couple options:

```
[~, ind] = ismember([{b(1).b.c}],[{c(1).b.c}])
```

and casting to cell array:

```
[~,idx]=ismember(struct2cell(b(1).b),struct2cell(c(1).b))
idx=reshape(idx,1,3);
```

For both output should be:

```
2 1 3
```

Comment: I still get the same error... and using struct2cell I get the error `Undefined function 'struct2cell' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`